# SQL code to add missing StartDate between 2 dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table ordered by clientID, contractID and effectiveDate. One Client has multiple contractID and it's respective effectiveDate.

[image]

the desired output is as below, where the new FYStartDate column should add the missing FYStartDate between 2 dates of subsequent contractIDs of a clientID(in this scenario, Fiscal Year starts on 01June of every year)

[image]

**I would be appreciate if you could share the required SQL code.**

I'm attaching the SQL code to generate the first table

```
CREATE TABLE [client] (
[clientid] [int] NULL,
[contractid] [int] NULL,
[effectivedate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO 

insert into [client] values
('228','2','6/1/2003'),('228','136','6/1/2004'),('228','242','6/1/2008'), 
('228','337','12/1/2012'),('228','584','6/1/2017'),('14216','319','5/1/2013'), 
('14216','355','6/1/2013'),('14216','739','6/1/2020'),('14216','10','3/1/2021'), 
('14216','1009','6/1/2021')
```

Comment: Do you have a table of dates where you store the financial years? *(You should. It will allow you to solve half the problem simply by joining on to that "calendar" table.)*

Comment: If a contact is superceded by a new contract Mid Year, why don't both contracts have entries for that year? (The first contract for the first part of the financial year, the second contract for the second part of the same financial year?)

Comment: There is a Date table, but it doesn't have FY related columns. I've created the required FY related columns and I'm updating the question with a link to the Excel file containing the required date table. If I get the desired output, I will recommend the  client to add the FY columns to the Date table.

Comment: Please don't use links to external documents, images, etc. Copy the relevant information as formatted text directly in to your question. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I will not be clicking on linked Excel docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted without as @MatBailie suggest about having more structured data. To accomplish what you ask, each record needs to know when the contract before it and after it comes into effect. I think you need to play with the ordering because I didn't quite get how to order the results... by clientid, contractid, dates, etc?

UPDATED: see comments. Changed some CTEs, JOINS and ORDER BY for better partitioning by `clientid`.

```
CREATE TABLE [client] (
[clientid] [int] NULL,
[contractid] [int] NULL,
[effectivedate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
;

insert into [client] values
('228','2','6/1/2003'),('228','136','6/1/2004'),('228','242','6/1/2008'), 
('228','337','12/1/2012'),('228','584','6/1/2017'),('14216','319','5/1/2013'), 
('14216','355','6/1/2013'),('14216','739','6/1/2020'),('14216','10','3/1/2021'), 
('14216','1009','6/1/2021')
;

--Need a sequence of numbers to create a sequence of fiscal years.
WITH x AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as x(a)
), y as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tens.a, ones.a) as row_num
  FROM x as ones, x as tens
), fiscYears as (
  SELECT
    fyStart = DATEFROMPARTS(2000 + y.row_num -1, 6, 1)
    , fyEnd = DATEFROMPARTS(2000 + y.row_num, 5, 31)
  FROM y

--Need to order the client records by effective date.
--From updated question... looks like we are reporting by clientid.
), clientOrd as (
  SELECT c2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c2.clientid ORDER BY c2.effectivedate) as row_num
      FROM client c2

--For each contract, get the previous and next contracts by effective date.
), clientWNext as (
  SELECT c.*
    , cNext.effectivedate as nextEffectiveDate
    , cPrev.effectivedate as prevEffectiveDate
  FROM clientOrd as c
    LEFT JOIN clientOrd as cNext
      ON cNext.clientid = c.clientid
      AND cNext.row_num = c.row_num + 1
    LEFT JOIN clientOrd as cPrev
      ON cPrev.clientid = c.clientid
      AND cPrev.row_num = c.row_num - 1
)
SELECT
  c.clientid
  , cwn.contractid
  , CASE WHEN cwn.effectiveDate >= fy.fyStart AND cwn.effectiveDate <= fy.fyEnd 
      THEN  cwn.effectivedate
      ELSE null
    END as effectivedate
  , fy.fyStart
FROM fiscYears as fy
  --To get a full FY range for each client, we join to a distinct list of clients.
  JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT clientid FROM client
  ) as c
    ON 1=1

  --Need to join the list of contracts.
  INNER JOIN clientWNext as cwn
    ON cwn.clientid = c.clientid
  
    --This is the main join criteria where the effective date is within the fy year start/end.
    AND ((
      cwn.effectivedate >= fy.fyStart
      AND cwn.effectivedate <= fy.fyEnd
    ) 

    --This is the "alternate" join criteria where the previous contrat is still in effect
    --but there is no new contract to supercede the previous.
    OR (
      cwn.prevEffectiveDate < fy.fyStart
      AND cwn.effectiveDate < fy.fyStart
      AND (cwn.nextEffectiveDate > fy.fyEnd OR cwn.nextEffectiveDate IS NULL)
    ))

--Limiting fiscal year date range.
WHERE fy.fyStart >= '1/1/2003'
  AND fy.fyStart < '1/1/2024'
ORDER BY c.clientid, fy.fyStart, cwn.effectivedate
```

| clientid | contractid | effectivedate | fyStart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 228 | 2 | 2003-06-01 | 2003-06-01 |
| 228 | 136 | 2004-06-01 | 2004-06-01 |
| 228 | 136 | *null* | 2005-06-01 |
| 228 | 136 | *null* | 2006-06-01 |
| 228 | 136 | *null* | 2007-06-01 |
| 228 | 242 | 2008-06-01 | 2008-06-01 |
| 228 | 242 | *null* | 2009-06-01 |
| 228 | 242 | *null* | 2010-06-01 |
| 228 | 242 | *null* | 2011-06-01 |
| 228 | 337 | 2012-12-01 | 2012-06-01 |
| 228 | 337 | *null* | 2013-06-01 |
| 228 | 337 | *null* | 2014-06-01 |
| 228 | 337 | *null* | 2015-06-01 |
| 228 | 337 | *null* | 2016-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | *null* | 2018-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | *null* | 2019-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | *null* | 2020-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | *null* | 2021-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | *null* | 2022-06-01 |
| 228 | 584 | *null* | 2023-06-01 |
| 14216 | 319 | 2013-05-01 | 2012-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | 2013-06-01 | 2013-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | *null* | 2014-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | *null* | 2015-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | *null* | 2016-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | *null* | 2017-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | *null* | 2018-06-01 |
| 14216 | 355 | *null* | 2019-06-01 |
| 14216 | 739 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-01 |
| 14216 | 10 | 2021-03-01 | 2020-06-01 |
| 14216 | 1009 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-01 |
| 14216 | 1009 | *null* | 2022-06-01 |
| 14216 | 1009 | *null* | 2023-06-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mjYDvT8Q)

Comment: Really appreciate your solution. The output is almost as required. the ORDER BY sequence is c.clientid, c.effectivedate.

the only missing part is, 4 FY start dates (17,18,19) are missing between ClientID:14216, ContractID:355 & ClientID:14216, ContractID:739

Comment: In the meantime, I've updated my question with a link to Excel file containing the DimDate with required FY columns. Can you recommend a solution using this DimDate?

Comment: @Vickar with your updated sort criteria, I updated the answer. Since the FY range seems to be an independent report by `clientid`, I updated the `clientOrd` and `clientNext` CTEs to include partitioning by `clientid`. Also updated the main `SELECT ... JOINs` to include `clientid`. To filter out FY prior to any contract being established, I changed the `LEFT OUTER JOIN clientWNext` to an `INNER JOIN`. And finally, I updated the `ORDER BY` based on your comment above.